# Why does job submission from Java fail?

Tags: spring, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I submit a Spark job from Java as a RESTful service. I keep getting the following error:

> Application application_1446816503326_0098 failed 2 times due to AM 
>   Container for appattempt_1446816503326_0098_000002 exited with
>   exitCode: -1000   For more detailed output, check application tracking
>   page:http://ip-172-31-34-
>   108.us-west-2.compute.internal:8088/proxy/application_1446816503326_0098/Then,
>   click on links to logs of each attempt. Diagnostics: 
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/opt/apache-tomcat-
>   8.0.28/webapps/RESTfulExample/WEB-INF/lib/spark-yarn_2.10-1.3.0.jar does not  exist Failing this attempt. Failing the application.

`spark-yarn_2.10-1.3.0.jar` file is there in the `lib` folder.

Here is my program.

```
package SparkSubmitJava;

import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientArguments;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/spark")
public class JavaRestService {

@GET
@Path("/{param}/{param2}/{param3}")
public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String bedroom,@PathParam("param2") String bathroom,@PathParam("param3")String area) throws IOException {
String[] args = new String[] {
"--name",
"JavaRestService",
    "--driver-memory",
    "1000M",     
    "--jar",
    "/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/webapps/scalatest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar",
    "--class",
    "ScalaTest.ScalaTest.ScalaTest",
    "--arg",
    bedroom,
    "--arg",
    bathroom,
    "--arg",
    area,
    "--arg",
    "yarn-cluster",    
};
Configuration config = new Configuration();
System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
ClientArguments cArgs = new ClientArguments(args, sparkConf); 
Client client = new Client(cArgs, config, sparkConf); 
client.run(); 
return Response.status(200).entity(client).build();
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is this file /opt/apache-tomcat- 8.0.28/webapps/RESTfulExample/WEB-INF/lib/spark-yarn_2.10-1.3.0.jar present?

Comment: yes ...and also i changed the path like /home/ec2-user/filename.. but still i was facing same issue